# Why do I need save-config with kubctl apply?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

`kubectl apply <file.yaml> --save-config` creates or updates a deployment and saves the deployment as metadata.

In the documentation it says

> --save-config[=false]: If true, the configuration of current object will be saved in its annotation. This is useful when you want to perform kubectl apply on this object in the future.

Why do I need `save-config`? I can still update my deployment using `kubectl apply` if I do not `--save-config`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### kubectl apply

`kubectl apply` use the data in an annotation `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` to see e.g. if any fields has been removed since the last apply. This is needed because some fields or annotations may have been added live in the cluster by e.g. a controller or mutating webhook.

See e.g. [Understanding the Kubectl Apply Command](https://luispreciado.blog/posts/kubernetes/core-concepts/kubectl-apply)

> I can still update my deployment using kubectl apply if I do not --save-config

Yes, `--save-config` is only used when migrating from an *imperative* workflow. See more details below. The following `kubectl apply` commands does not need `--save-config` flag because the annotation is already there.

### Workflows with kubectl

When working with configurations for Kubernetes, this can be done in multiple ways, they are both *imperative* or *declarative*:

- [Managing Kubernetes Objects Using Imperative Commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/)
- [Imperative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-config/)
- [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)

`kubectl apply` is used for *declarative* configuration management.

### Migrating from imperative to declarative config mangement

Using `kubectl` with the `--save-config` flag is a way to write config to the annotation `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` that `kubectl apply` uses. This is useful when migrating from an *imperative*  to an *declarative* workflow.

- [Migrating from imperative command management to declarative object configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#migrating-from-imperative-command-management-to-declarative-object-configuration)
- [Migrating from imperative object configuration to declarative object configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#migrating-from-imperative-object-configuration-to-declarative-object-configuration)

Comment: Okay. So the question is "when does apply update a field?" And this is true, if the field is in the last applied configuration.