# No field manager for service account with kubectl create, but there with kubectl apply

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-controller-manager, server-side-apply

I create an empty service account on a CAPI cluster

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
```

with kubectl create and kubectl apply.

**kubectl create**

```
$ k get sa -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2024-01-24T15:11:24Z"
    name: build-robot
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "7337504"
    uid: e2414d28-d897-4099-ac5d-699c89835615
  secrets:
  - name: build-robot-token-77p6d
```

**kubectl apply**

```
$ k get sa -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"build-robot","namespace":"default"}}
    creationTimestamp: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:secrets:
          .: {}
          k:{"name":"build-robot-token-8rqgq"}: {}
      manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      time: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      time: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    name: build-robot
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "7337399"
    uid: 0bac2513-844f-4526-b374-3642bdf26838
  secrets:
  - name: build-robot-token-8rqgq
```

The “kubectl apply” service account gets a managed field (secrets) by `kube-controller-manager` while the one with “kubectl create” is unmanaged. I don’t understand this.

I tried the same experiment with a pod. All the managed fields in either case were same (except the ones that I expect to be different like `last-applied-configuration`).

**UPDATE**: As per ["kubectl create" without --save-config: why field managers present for Service but not for ServiceAccount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77888446/6740589), it seems that the field manager "kube-controller-manager" in "kubectl apply" is not there in later versions of kubernetes. It seems to be a bug in the version I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of "save-config" is false for kubectl create command because of which the configuration of object is not shown.  To view configuration of object please pass "save-config" as true for kubectl create  for ex:

```
kubectl create sa build-robot --save-config=true
```

More details of "save-config" are in [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

After creating object you can view the object configuration with "managedFields"

Comment: This was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942153/why-do-i-need-save-config-with-kubctl-apply

Comment: Why does kube-controller-manager declaratively modify the resource? Does it see that the object was created imperatively and follow it as well? In other words, does kube-controller-manager work differently by seeing if the object was created imperatively or declaratively?

Comment: More importantly, why is config stored for pod with 'kubectl create' without --save-config flag?

Comment: When kubectl "create" is used for creating resources it will save configuration in annotation of object.  Its same for pod as well.   Without "save-config" flag during create will not update annotation of the object.

Comment: I understand that "kubectl create" without "save-config" won't add the "last-applied-configuration" annotation. What about the field manager "kube-controller-manager" working differently for service account vs pod? I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888446/kubectl-create-without-save-config-why-field-managers-present-for-service-b

Comment: using "saved-config" will store information in object annotation under "metadata" i didnt mean "last-applied-configuration"

Comment: Is the interaction between the resource and kube-controller-manager dependent on if I do "kubectl create" vs "kubectl apply"? I would think that this interaction is different from me creating a resource.