# "kubectl create" without --save-config: why field managers present for Service but not for ServiceAccount

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-controller-manager, server-side-apply

This is in continuation to the question [No field manager for service account with kubectl create, but there with kubectl apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880167/no-field-manager-for-service-account-with-kubectl-create-but-there-with-kubectl).
The `Service` (or `Pod`) created with "kubectl apply" and "kubectl create" in a CAPI cluster gets all the same managed fields (except the expected ones like `last-applied-configuration`). But this does not seem to be the case for `ServiceAccount` as mentioned in the above question.

#### For Service (or Pod)

**kubectl create**

```
$ k get svc my-service -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-26T18:40:15Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2024-01-26T18:40:15Z"
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "548809"
  uid: 7d57743d-9b8d-4f04-850b-7ca6d5e1347a
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.19.186.161
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.19.186.161
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**kubectl apply**

```
$ k get svc my-service -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":9376}],"selector":{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"MyApp"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-26T18:41:00Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:spec:
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2024-01-26T18:41:00Z"
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "548931"
  uid: 8a378bcc-b70e-441b-8b55-463f7700e1f3
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.19.141.7
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.19.141.7
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Result: The managedFields are (almost) same.

#### For ServiceAccount

**kubectl create**

```
$ k get sa -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2024-01-24T15:11:24Z"
    name: build-robot
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "7337504"
    uid: e2414d28-d897-4099-ac5d-699c89835615
  secrets:
  - name: build-robot-token-77p6d
```

**kubectl apply**

```
$ k get sa -oyaml --show-managed-fields
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"build-robot","namespace":"default"}}
    creationTimestamp: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:secrets:
          .: {}
          k:{"name":"build-robot-token-8rqgq"}: {}
      manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      time: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      time: "2024-01-24T15:10:55Z"
    name: build-robot
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "7337399"
    uid: 0bac2513-844f-4526-b374-3642bdf26838
  secrets:
  - name: build-robot-token-8rqgq
```

Result: The managedFields are different; completely absent in the case of "kubectl create". Why? What changed?

Comment: Version of cluster and CLI?

Comment: Cluster: v1.23.10, CLI: v1.25.13

Comment: @VIAGC Any clues?

Comment: I'll recommned you to reproduce this with latest versions too, if possible, there can be bugs that are fixed, and I don't want to deep dive into bug  finding.

Comment: You are correct. Can't reproduce it in `Client Version: v1.29.1, Server Version: v1.28.4`. I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @VIAGC If you can, can you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77917605/6740589 as well? Any docs or reading material if there, please point me.

Comment: That is a long question with many subquestions. There are a lot of docs you can go through, but I'll shamelessly plug in an article I wrote https://while-vyom-is-coding.hashnode.dev/i-just-use-kubectl-apply. See if it answers any of those questions, if not, I'll see what can I help you with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the issue in version: `server: v1.23.10, client: v1.25.13`.
Can't reproduce it in `server: v1.28.4, client: v1.29.1`.