# Managed fields in "kubectl scale"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, server-side-apply

```
Version:   
 Client: "v1.25.13"   
 Server: "v1.26.8"
also tested in
  Client: v1.29.1
  Server: v1.28.4
```

I create a Deployment and perform `kubectl scale` and `kubectl edit` in the given order. **The observations and questions are for the field `replicas`**.

```
1. apply: "replicas" not specified in the yaml; assumes default value of 1; 
   still a managed field managed by 'kubectl-client-side-apply' & 'kube-controller-manager'
2. scaled from 1 to 3: managed by 'kube-controller-manager' & 'kubectl' subresource 'scale'
3. scaled from 3 to 0: no ownership; unmanaged
4. scaled from 0 to 1: only owned by 'kube-controller-manager'
5. edit from 1 to 0: owned by 'kubectl-edit' only
6. scaled from 0 to 1: owned by 'kube-controller-manager' and 'kubectl' subresource 'scale'
7. scaled from 1 to 0: no ownership; unmanaged
8. edit 0 to 1: owned by 'kube-controller-manager' and 'kubectl-edit'
```

Q1. In (2), why is the ownership revoked by 'kubectl-client-side-apply'?
Q2. In (3), it seems like very weird behaviour. Does it mean that having a value of 0 shouldn't be owned? What is different about `replicas=0`?
Q3. In (4), why isn't it also owned by 'kubectl' with subresource 'scale'?
Q4. In (5), unlike (3) when with "kubectl scale", there are no memberships for replicas=0, why is it owned by "kubectl edit" now?
Q5. In (6), unlike (4), how are "kubectl edit" and "kubectl scale" different?

This is the yaml used for reference:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: demo-pvc-claim
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  storageClassName: nutanix-volume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: clear-nginx-deployment
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: clear-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: clear-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: clear-nginx
        image: clearlinux/nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html
          name: site-data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: site-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: demo-pvc-claim
```

Comment: As per **[open git issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99003)**, **1)** The ownership is not revoked by `kubectl-client-side-apply`. It is still owned by `kubectl-client-side-apply` and `kube-controller-manager`. **2)** Yes, it means that having a value of 0 shouldn't be owned. This is because when the replicas value is 0, the Deployment is effectively deleted. So there is no need to manage the replicas field.

Comment: **3)** It is also owned by `kubectl` along with `kube-controller-manager`.

Comment: **4)** and **5)** `kubectl edit` can be used to update the replicas field, but `kubectl scale` cannot be used to update other fields in the deployment. So,`kubectl edit` is a full resource update operation that can update any field in the Deployment. When you use `kubectl scale` to set the replicas field to 0, you are unable to effectively delete the deployment with the help of `scale`.Refer to the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-edit) for more details.

Comment: 3) I rechecked. Its only owned by `kube-controller-manager`

Comment: 1) I don't see the behavior in the versions I tried. The git issue refers to quite an old version 1.19.

Comment: 2) "the Deployment is effectively deleted". I disagree. The pods of the deployment are deleted. That shouldn't mean we don't care who wants the replicas to be 0. SSA came to resolve the problem of accidental overwrites. I don't understand why zero case would be any different. Anyway, if this is the expected behavior, this isn't the forum to discuss this point.